# Derivatives- Application

Tags: derivatives

Assume that spherical raindrop evaporates at a rate proportional to its surface area. If its original radius is  3mm and one hour later, it reduces to 2mm, find an expression for the radius of the raindrop at any time.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the surface area given the radius?

Comment: Yes. I do @henrik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dV}{dt} = k \cdot 4\pi r^2$$  ($k$ is constant of proportionality)

$V= \dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ for a sphere, so 
$$\frac{dV}{dt}= 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$$
Compare both $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$.  You get $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=k$.

Integrating, you get $r=kt+c$.  For $t=0, r=3$ and for $t=1, r=2$  ($r$ is in mm and $t$ is in hours).  Solving for above values of $r$ and $t$, you get $r=3-t$.

Comment: sry for poor syntax...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: thnx, it was helpful.